# arrayOutOfBounds exception java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to parse a text file and build a tree from it according to the rules i specified in the addToTree method. However, im getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at ie.gmit.TreeTest.addToTree(TreeTest.java:27)
at ie.gmit.TreeTest.parse(TreeTest.java:20)
at ie.gmit.TreeTest.main(TreeTest.java:77)
```

addChar1 and addChar2 are nodes that I created from the passing in the word in the parse method

here is the code:

```
public class TreeTest {

public void parse(File f) throws Exception {
    Node root = new  Node('+'); //create a root node
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));

    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
        String[] words = line.toLowerCase().split(" ");

        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
            addToTree(words[i], root);
        }
    }
}

public void addToTree(String s, Node root){
    char[] characters = s.toCharArray();
    Node addChar1 = new Node(characters[0]);
    Node addChar2 = new Node(characters[1]);
    Node fullWord = new Node(s);

    //get the child nodes of the root
    Node[] rootChildren = root.children();
    //get the child nodes of the first node (addChar1)
    Node[] addChar1Children = addChar1.children();

    //get each child of the root
    for(int i=0; i<rootChildren.length; i++){
        Node rootChild = rootChildren[i];
        //see if the addChar1 already exists in the tree
        //if it doesn't
        if(!rootChild.equals(addChar1)){
            //add the addChar1 as a child of the root
            root.addChild(addChar1);
            //add the addChar2 as a child of the addChar1 also
            addChar1.addChild(addChar2);
            //insert the whole word as the child of the addChar2
            addChar2.addChild(fullWord);
        }
        //if the addChar1 exists in the tree already
        else{
            // get each child of the addChar1
            for(int j=0; j<addChar1Children.length; j++){
                Node addChar1Child = addChar1Children[i];
                //see if the addChar2 already exists in the tree
                //if it doesn't
                if(!addChar1Child.equals(addChar2)){
                    //add the addChar2 as the child if the addChar1
                    addChar1.addChild(addChar2);
                    //add the actual word
                    addChar2.addChild(fullWord);
                }
                //if the addChar2 exists the the tree already
                else{
                    //insert the whole word as the child of the FOUND NODE
                    addChar1Child.addChild(fullWord);
                }
            }//end of second for loop
        }
    }//end of the first for loop

}//end of addToTree

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     TreeTest test = new TreeTest();

     File f = new File("textFile.txt");
     test.parse(f);
 }
```

}

Anyone would help ?
all that the file contains:

"website which allows its users to add  modify or delete its content via web browser usually"

the Node class:

```
   public class Node<E> {

    private Node parent;
    private String fullWord;
    private char character; // value inside a node
    private boolean word; // put a true flag if the node is a word eg 'a'
    private List<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();  //creates a list of array list objects

    //** constructors **/
    public Node(){

    }

    public Node(String fullWord){
        this.fullWord = fullWord;
    }

    public Node(Node parent){
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Node(char character){
        this.character = character;
    }

    public Node(boolean word){
        this.word = word;
    }

    public Node(Node parent, char character){
        this(parent);
        this.character = character;
    }

    public Node(Node parent, char character, boolean word){
        this(parent);
        this.character = character;
        this.word = word;
    }

    //** methods **/
    public boolean isRoot(){
        return this.parent ==  null;
    }

    public boolean hasChildren(){
        return this.children.size() > 0;
    }

    public void addChild(Node child){
        child.setParent(this);
        children.add(child);
    }

    public Node getParent(){
        return this.parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Node parent){
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Node[] children(){
        return (Node[]) children.toArray(new Node [children.size()]);
    }

    public char getItem() {
        return character;
    }
```

}

Comment: Are you sure your process isn't somehow pulling empty strings from the input file? The obvious culprit would be your assumption that the input strings are all >= 2 in length.

Comment: actually all the words in the file are >=2 in length

Comment: @ciastkoo - all the words in your file may be >= 2 in length, but you can still be pulling empty strings from the file, depending on how you're doing it. You might want to check the length of the input string in the method, to be sure.

Comment: @Perception could you explain how could I be pulling empty strings ?

Comment: @ciastkoo Do you have an empty line in your input file?

Comment: @Perception I have only 1 line in the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

char[] characters = s.toCharArray();  // check characters array length then write characters[1]

Answer (score 0):

Check this line (27):

```
Node addChar1 = new Node(characters[0]);
```

Does the `String` being passed in contain any characters? Check that you don't have an empty line in your input file.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check index 0 and 1 before accessing them:

```
if (!s.isEmpty()) {
       char[] characters = s.toCharArray();
       Node addChar1 = new Node(characters[0]);
       Node addChar2 = new Node(characters[1]);
...
```

You obviously have some empty string.

Answer (score 0):

When you use this code

```
Node addChar1 = new Node(characters[0]);
Node addChar2 = new Node(characters[1]);
```

You should check the size of characters array before accessing indexed elements. When characters array size is less than 2 then you will get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: the file doesn't contain the words that are 3+ in length

Comment: Well, you said it doesn't contain words that are 3+ in length. How about empty words or words with 1 or 2 characters coming through?